# using visual C++ compiler in matlab

Tags: matlab, compiler-construction, loadlibrary

i installed two compilers in Matlab : LCC and Visual C++ 2008

i want to load a C++ header file in matlab but when i want to do this matlab uses LCC instead of

Visual C++ and gives me some warnings .

i used:

```
 mex -setup
 mbuild -setup
```

but Matlab still uses LCC for loading my C++ header file

```
>> loadlibrary('DLLing.dll', 'DLLTutorial.h')
```

Warning: Message from C preprocessor:

lcc preprocessor error: C:\Users\MAHNAZ\Documents\MATLAB\DLLTutorial.h:3 Could not find include file

How can i say to Matlab that use visual c++ compiler instead of LCC??

Answer (score 1):

What version of MatLab are you using? It might not suppose the version of the Microsoft SDK you have installed on your computer. This isn't really an answer but I can't post comments yet.

Comment: i use Matlab 7.6.0(R2008a) and i have Visual c++ 2008 installed

this is one of the compilers that R2008a supports

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with the install of Visual C++ '08? Have you tried reinstalling it? If you do make sure you select 32-bit. Maybe something got messed up when it was installed.

Answer (score 0):

As per your description, after you type `mex -setup`, the first thing MATLAB should ask you:

```
Please choose your compiler for building external interface (MEX) files:
Would you like mex to locate installed compilers [y]/n?
```

After this, you should press `y` and then you should see a list of available compilers. Choose a right one from them.

Comment: i do all of these correctly.
i use mex -setup and after that i choose visual c++ compiler
but i don't know why matlab using lcc when i want to use loadlibrary function .

Answer (score 0):

What version of Windows are you working with, is it 32 or 64 bit (question for both Windows and the MATLAB version installed)?

Looking the archived documentation for R2008a (you must be logged in to see the page), it [seems](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2008a/techdoc/ref/loadlibrary.html#brkxrbh-1) that LOADLIBRARY requires VS2005 on 64-bit platforms (perhaps it defaults to LCC if its not available). The truth is it does not explicitly say how it determines what compiler to use. (If you are up to it, you can `edit loadlibrary.m` and trace the execution to see why it ends up calling LCC instead of Visual C++)

Compare this with the [current](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/loadlibrary.html) R2012a help page where it clearly says that you must select the compiler with `mex -setup`.

Note that LCC compiler will no longer be shipped with future versions.

Comment: thanks
i use widows 32 bit and Matlab 32 bit
i saw the list of supported compilers for R2008a 32 bit and visual c++ 2008 is on the list but for loadlibrary function i don't know why it dosn't work??